# Automatic build of GAE maven project from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I have a google app engine project with java using maven, and every time I want to see the changes I made even to a simple jsp or html, I have to run clean install then run the server. I want to know if it's possible to see the changes without having to go through this long process.

I have a GAE project structure that contains a war and ear folders.
I run the clean install on the war, then I go to the ear folder to run the "appengine:devapp".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to make the development process more agile and see the changes on JSP/HTML files w/o having to redeploy the whole application again. In a nutshell, all you need to do is to copy the files to the target directory. There are several ways to do that, ANT is one of the options.

I friend of mine wrote an article several months ago explaining this process in more details. Take a look: http://fabiouechi.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/smart-appengine-devserver-restarts-for.html

cheers!